# Transit by road through Kenya

Tags: road-trips, uganda, carnet-de-passage, kenya, malawi

I am planning to travel to Jinja in Uganda from Malawi. I wish to transit through Kenya spending probably max two nights in the process, possibly only one night.  We can't get a Carnet for the vehicle in Malawi, it has to be done through AA South Africa and I don't have the time to wait. Min 10 days. The vehicle will have a Temporary Export Permit from Malawi with Police clearance Report etc.  It also is a duty free import here and Title Holder is actually Malawi Revenue Authority, so it can't be sold.  I will be traveling on Comesa Yellow card third party insurance, which is acceptable through to Uganda.

Do I take the chance and drive through to the Kenyan Border and see if they will allow me through or is there anyone I can contact for assistance?

Comment: Legally you shouldn't get through Kenya without a Carnet however borders are sometimes "fluid". Since this is an old question how did it go?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while an amazing trip, he's technically asking if he should 'chance it' breaking the law.  It's Africa and laws bend at borders with cash, but it was decided early on we wouldn't endorse this :(